# Difference between java.net exceptions (Specifically, no connection)

Tags: java, exception

I'm working on a program that parses a large amount of URLs and grabs images from the links. However, I'm trying to see what to do if I lose connection (i.e. internet drops). How can I differentiate between that as opposed to the URL leading to a 404 error?

Comment: What code do you use? When an exception is thrown, do you inspect `.getCause()`?

Comment: @fge `.getCause()` shows me an `UnknownHostException` when using the Twitter4j library, but I also have some code that'll throw a `SocketTimeoutException` (which gets properly thrown) when there's no connection.